# $f$ continuously differentiable implies even or odd?

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous and Riemann integrable such that $\int f(x)\,dx = F(x)+c$. My question is:

> Can we conclude that $F$ must be either odd or even?

In other words, can we rule out the possibility that it is neither? I would like to use this fact in a proof if it is so, but I haven't been able to prove it or provide a counter example.

Comment: what happens when you start with a $F$ which is not even or odd, and let $f$ be its derivative?

Comment: Exiitingcorpse: that doesn't quite work in full generality. Start with $F(x)=x+1$, so that $f(x)=1$. However, in doing the integration, we might just as well choose $G(x)=x$ in place of $F$, and the OP asks if we can rule out the possibility of *any* antiderivative being even or odd.

The claim comes down to "if $F$ is continuously differentiable, is there always $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $F+c$ is even or odd?" Daniel Rust gives a counterexample below. Here is a polynomial one: try $F(x)=x^2+2x+1$. Then $f(x)=2x+2$. Now try to show that *every* function $x^2+2x+C$ is neigher even nor odd.

Comment: this is all true, i just meant as a way to think of a possible (explicit) counter example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surely $f(x)=e^x$ is a counter example.